# dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0{number}.severity = error doesn't prevent project from building

Tags: c#, .net, editorconfig

When I add dotnet_diagnostic.IDE{}.severity = error inmy .editorconfig file, I see red underline in my code but I can still build and run my project. Is it how it should work? I don't think so, How can I fix it?

I expect project which cannot be builded. I cannot build my project when I set severity = error for naming rules and I expect the same for IDE code rules

Comment: The red underline in your code is for an error with an error code that is prefixed with IDE? What is the error code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: IDE0040 is rule I'm testing but I don't think it matters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSBuild - Treat Warnings from editorconfig as Errors (enforce during build)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470838/msbuild-treat-warnings-from-editorconfig-as-errors-enforce-during-build)

Comment: Yes, it really helped. Thanks