# Is there a way to enforce editconfig settings during build for C++ solution with MSBuild (Visual C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've seen it's possible for [Net solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470838/msbuild-treat-warnings-from-editorconfig-as-errors-enforce-during-build) or when using [Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866609/can-clang-format-tell-me-if-formatting-changes-are-necessary) but I'm wondering if VS2022 has something to enforce this.

Thanks!