How to enforce IDE0300 diagnostic in Visual Studio?
I am trying to enforce the Use collection expression for array (IDE0300) in a C# project. In the .editorconfig file located at the root of my solution, I added the following
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = crlf
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

[*.{json,yml,csproj,props,targets}]
indent_size = 2

[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0300.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-Style.severity = error

Running the dotnet build still build with no issues even when my project has lots of IDE0300 suggestions

I've added the description of the diagnostic to your post. It's always better when people don't have to follow a link away from this site in order to figure out what you're asking about - adding the link should be to allow them to go get additional information, not requirerd information.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470838/msbuild-treat-warnings-from-editorconfig-as-errors-enforce-during-build
